# html page loses style after run with nginx

Tags: html, css, nginx

I have a template that I was testing. once I open the template with chrome by navigating into its folder, it works. But when I give nginx the directory and then I type localhost/index.html the file opens but looses all style. once I navigate and open with chrome, it works perfectly and it shows in the url: file:///var/www/html/sidebar-09-1/sidebar-09/index.html

why does the page lose style after running with nginx or apache2.
The console shows several erros:

```js
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $.scrollUp is not a function TypeError: $.scrollUp is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/js/main.js:15:11)
    at l (http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js:2:29567)
    at c (http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js:2:29869) undefined
w.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $.scrollUp is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:15)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost/js/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

index.html code is as follows:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Sidebar 09</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
        
        <div class="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div class="custom-menu">
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-primary">
            </button>
        </div>
            <div class="img bg-wrap text-center py-4" style="background-image: url(images/bg_1.jpg);">
                <div class="user-logo">
                    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(images/logo.jpg);"></div>
                    <h3>Catriona Henderson</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled components mb-5">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home mr-3"></span> Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-download mr-3 notif"><small class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">5</small></span> Download</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-gift mr-3"></span> Gift Code</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-trophy mr-3"></span> Top Review</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-cog mr-3"></span> Settings</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-support mr-3"></span> Support</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-sign-out mr-3"></span> Sign Out</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content  -->
      <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">
        <h2 class="mb-4">Sidebar #09</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
        </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the browser's console? Does the CSS file have the proper permissions on the server?

Comment: @j08691 I am getting several erros on the console. I updated the question

Comment: Also check the dev tool's network tab for the CSS file. Specifically the status column

Comment: @j08691 the status is 200 for all files listed